# Sending newline/enter character from vim to tmux via vimtux

Tags: python, vim, tmux

I am using Brauner's vimtux plugin for sending commands to a running python-REPL. I use the following definitions for sending either the current selection, paragraph or line to tmux.

```
au FileType python vnoremap "+y:call SendToTmux('%paste')<cr>
au FileType python nnoremap V}"+y:call SendToTmux('%paste')<cr>
au FileType python nnoremap yy:call SendToTmux(@")<cr>j
```

I have been tinkering for ages now, what I should add to the `SendToTmux('%paste')` such that this line is in fact evaluated, too. Currently, I always have to switch to the tmux-session in order to press `<cr>`. The `SendToTmux(@")` is catching the EOL, so this works like a bliss.

Comment: Maybe `call SendToTmux('%paste<cr>')`?

Comment: Why don't you ask that on the plugin's issue tracker?

Comment: @andlrc: No, this would literary send the string '%paste<cr>'. I probably would need to add a EOL-character, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @romainl: I already did so a few days ago, but haven't received an answer yet. https://github.com/brauner/vimtux/issues/1

Comment: Don't be so impatient ;-)

Comment: @ThomasMöbius Try adding `^M`, eg press `<C-v>` and enter.

Comment: @andlrc: This  throws exceptions E115: Fehlendes Anführungszeichen: '%paste
E116: Ungültige Argumente für die Funktion SendToTmux